# is it possible to make a recylce view for this?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I was thinking at first to hard code this, but in the end recycle view is much more suitable, I am not sure though how I can create a recycle view for this. would I need 2 separate vies, one for each row?

(my code is in java not kotlin)

**the question is regarding the 4 little squares in the photo**

The big square at the top is static and will always be there and so I don't need recycle view for that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the recycler view , set the layout manager to grid layout :

```
Integer columnnumber = 2;

recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),columnnumber));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an item row for one item, and then use the `GridLayoutManager` as the RecyclerView's LayoutManager. With `GridLayoutManager` you can set how many columns do you want to have in each row.